# Link between two webbrowser controls

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I'm using two web browsers in my application, one for displaying "content table" of a book as links and the other for displaying the content of this links

for exemple :

```
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#www_gutenberg_org@files@26178@26178-h@26178-h-0_htm_pgepubid00001">THE MIRROR OF TASTE,</a>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#www_gutenberg_org@files@26178@26178-h@26178-h-0_htm_pgepubid00002">DRAMATIC CENSOR.</a>
<ul>
<li>....
```

and i want to get to this links by click:

```
<div class="mirror"><a class="pageno" title="189" id="pgepubid00000"/> <a id="www_gutenberg_org@files@26178@26178-h@26178-h-0_htm_page189"/>
<h1 id="www_gutenberg_org@files@26178@26178-h@26178-h-0_htm_pgepubid00001">THE MIRROR OF TASTE,</h1>
<h6>AND</h6>
<h2 id="www_gutenberg_org@files@26178@26178-h@26178-h-0_htm_pgepubid00002">DRAMATIC CENSOR.</h2>
<table class="title" summary="title strip">
<tbody><tr>
<td>Vol. I.</td>
<td class="center">MARCH 1810.</td>
<td class="right">No. 3.</td>
</tr>
```

each part is in one web browser

Comment: are you sure you mean web browsers? maybe you want frames

Comment: i tried both and i gives the same result( i'm working offline)

Comment: @sansa.med. Can you define what you mean by Browser?

Comment: I'm guessing the System.Windows.Forms WebBrowser control?

Comment: i have html to display, this html define the content of an eBook, so i found that it can be displayed on a web browser or a frame, yes a control

Comment: ah ok. Is your project winforms? WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by hooking into the navigate event on the webBrowser control, taking the destination and applying it to the other browser. You cancel the navigate event if you find a link you want to apply elsewhere. But, I used a hosted winforms WebBrowser control

In order to determine when to apply to the other browser, I put data in the link that I was able to parse out.

Comment: @sansa.med 1. Register for WebBrowser.Navigating. 2. Set e.Cancel to true. 3. Parse EventArgs.Url. 4. Profit.